# Unable to load shared library 'libldap-2.4.so.2' or one of its dependencies

Tags: .net, linux, docker, ubuntu, directoryservices

Team,

I am getting the following error when trying to run on docker. its working fine on windows machine-

> Unable to load shared library 'libldap-2.4.so.2' or one of its
> dependencies. In order to help diagnose loading problems, consider
> setting the LD_DEBUG environment variable: liblibldap-2.4.so.2: cannot
> open shared object file: No such file or directory

i am using the System.DirectoryServices.Protocols namespace for LdapConnection. have tried to install libldap in my docker image. in the following 3 ways but none of them worked.

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install libldap-2.4-2


RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
        libldap-2.4-2 \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN apk add libldap
```

Here is my docker file

```
#See https://aka.ms/containerfastmode to understand how Visual Studio uses this Dockerfile to build your images for faster debugging.

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
        libldap-2.4-2 \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["Ldaptest1/Ldaptest1.csproj", "Ldaptest1/"]
RUN dotnet restore "Ldaptest1/Ldaptest1.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/Ldaptest1"
RUN dotnet build "Ldaptest1.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "Ldaptest1.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Ldaptest1.dll"]
```

i am currently using .NET 6 and it is breaking in the following line when initializing LdapConnection -

```
var connection = new LdapConnection(ldapDomain)
```

i have gone through this - https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-docker/issues/1946. but that did not help.

thanks in advance

Comment: The final image only contains the content starting from the final `FROM` line (and, in your case, since it's `FROM base`, the `base` stage as well).  Do you need to move the package installation into either the `base` or `final` stage, so the shared library is in the final image?

Comment: Did you ever get this to work. I am having the same issue now.

Comment: Hello, I know it's been a long time but if you add this line after your last FROM
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install libldap-2.4-2
it will work as expected, at least it worked for me

Comment: I could not add the RUN apt command after the last FROM so I added it after the EXPOSE 443. Otherwise I received the error: executor failed running [/bin/sh -c apt-get update ...]: exit code: 100

Answer (score 6):

Move your installations commands after your last FROM and that should fix it.

I had to do this for a .NET Core 5 image and it worked.

```
#See https://aka.ms/containerfastmode to understand how Visual Studio uses this Dockerfile to build your images for faster debugging.

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["Ldaptest1/Ldaptest1.csproj", "Ldaptest1/"]
RUN dotnet restore "Ldaptest1/Ldaptest1.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/Ldaptest1"
RUN dotnet build "Ldaptest1.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "Ldaptest1.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
        libldap-2.4-2 \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Ldaptest1.dll"]
```

Comment: In some cases apt-get installs libs to non standard path, and library 'libldap-2.4.so.2' may be not found after install. In this case you should connect to a container and via terminal find the library path. After that just add that new path to DockerFile by ENV command. Example: i have found lib in "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu", so i have to add: ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu"  just after (RUN apt-...  ...lists/*) command. So then your app will run in a container, the new location will be used for search library.